# Stuck with a For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, kaggle

I started to code not too long ago and I jumped into the Titanic exercise from Kaggle. I was trying to change the Nan value of the Age of some of the passengers into the Age I think it is fit for their Prefixes (Mr., Ms., Master...).

Tried to do a for loop but it seems not to work as it gives the same value to everyone with Nan value in Age regardless of their Prefix. What am I doing wrong and how could I make it right?

```
import math

for i in range(len(database)): 
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Capt.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Col.':
        database['Age'] = 65.0
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Sir.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Major.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Rev.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Lady.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Dr.':
        database['Age'] = 47.5
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Don.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Jonkheer.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mrs.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' the Countess.':
        database['Age'] = 36.5
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mr.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Ms.':
        database['Age'] = 29.0
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mme.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mlle.':
        database['Age'] = 24.0
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Miss.':
        database['Age'] = 21.0
    elif math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True and database['Prefix'][i] == ' Master.':
        database['Age'] = 3.5
```

This is BEFORE the for loop:
[Titanic1.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9AL7.png)
And this is AFTER the for loop:
[Titanic2.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRODS.png)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is ``database`` pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Is `database['Age'][i]` the correct way to access the element you want?  That does not seem to agree with the assignment statement `database['Age'] = 3.5`.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I guess it was a try to iterate over database..

Comment: @JohnGordon It is supposed to be `database["Age"][i] = 3.5`.

Comment: maybe the pythonic way of the java's switch-case could help you perfectly do what you want  https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things can be fixed regarding your code.

First, we will put the common element of all the if/elifs in a single if:

```
import math

for i in range(len(database)): 
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True:
        if database['Prefix'][i] == ' Capt.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Col.':
            database['Age'] = 65.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Sir.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Major.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Rev.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Lady.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Dr.':
            database['Age'] = 47.5
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Don.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Jonkheer.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mrs.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' the Countess.':
            database['Age'] = 36.5
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mr.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Ms.':
            database['Age'] = 29.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mme.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mlle.':
            database['Age'] = 24.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Miss.':
            database['Age'] = 21.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Master.':
            database['Age'] = 3.5
```

Then we will get rid of all the `database["Prefix"][i]` checks by saving that into a variable, and use the `in` operator to avoid many `prefix == "something" or prefix == "something else"`.

```
for i in range(len(database)): 
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True:
        prefix = database['Prefix'][i] 
        if prefix in (' Capt.', ' Col.'):
            database['Age'] = 65.0
        elif prefix in (' Sir.', ' Major.', ' Rev.', ' Lady.', ' Dr.'):
            database['Age'] = 47.5
        elif prefix in (' Don.', ' Jonkheer.', ' Mrs.', ' the Countess.'):
            database['Age'] = 36.5
        elif prefix (' Mr.', ' Ms.'):
            database['Age'] = 29.0
        elif prefix (' Mme.', ' Mlle.'):
            database['Age'] = 24.0
        elif prefix == ' Miss.':
            database['Age'] = 21.0
        elif prefix == ' Master.':
            database['Age'] = 3.5
```

Then, notice that you where modifying `database["Age"]` instead of `database["Age"][i]` so we'll fix that too.

```
for i in range(len(database)): 
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True:
        prefix = database['Prefix'][i] 
        if   prefix in (' Capt.', ' Col.'):                                age = 65.0
        elif prefix in (' Sir.', ' Major.', ' Rev.', ' Lady.', ' Dr.'):    age = 47.5
        elif prefix in (' Don.', ' Jonkheer.', ' Mrs.', ' the Countess.'): age = 36.5
        elif prefix (' Mr.', ' Ms.'):                                      age = 29.0
        elif prefix (' Mme.', ' Mlle.'):                                   age = 24.0
        elif prefix == ' Miss.':                                           age = 21.0
        elif prefix == ' Master.':                                         age = 3.5
        database['Age'][i] = age
```

Finally, if you wanted, you could write yourself a dictionary that matches prefixes with ages and use that to avoid the many if and elifs.

```
# Define how an age is matched with some prefixes.
ages_and_prefixes = ((65.0, ("Capt", "Col")),
                     (47.5, ("Sir", "Major", "Rev", "Lady", "Dr")),
                     (36.5, ("Don", "Jonkheer", "Mrs", "the Countess")),
                     (29.0, ("Mr", "Ms")),
                     (24.0, ("Mme", "Mlle")),
                     (21.0, ("Miss",)),
                     (3.5,  ("Master",))
                    )

prefix_to_age_dict = {}
for data in ages_and_prefixes:
    age = data[0]
    prefixes = data[1]
    for prefix in prefixes:
        prefix_to_age_dict[prefix] = age

# The replacement step in the database is now much simpler.
for i in range(len(database)):
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]):
        prefix = " " + database['Prefix'][i] + "."
        age = prefix_to_age_dict[prefix]
        database['Age'][i] = age
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this one. I keep checking it over and over to improve my for loops!

Comment: @jose.gp Glad it helps! I like to specify every little change, even though it makes answers longer, so that everyone can follow the reasoning and **why** / where the changes are made.

Answer (score 1):

Here's version with map that's a bit more simple to read than a longer for-loop:

```
prefix_dict = {" Capt.": 65.0, 
                " Col.": 65.0,
                " Sir.": 47.5, 
                " Major.": 47.5, 
                " Rev.": 47.5, 
                " Lady.": 47.5, 
                " Dr.": 47.5,
                " Don.": 36.5, 
                " Jonkheer.": 36.5, 
                " Mrs.": 36.5, 
                " the Countess.": 36.5,
                " Mr.": 29.0, 
                " Ms.": 29.0,
                " Mme.": 24.0,
                " Mlle.": 24.0,
                " Miss.": 21.0,
                " Master.": 3.5
                }


database.loc[database["Age"].isna(), 'Age'] = database.loc[database["Age"].isna(), 'Prefix'].map(lambda x: prefix_dict[x])
```

The `.isna()` will filter only n/a values while the `.map(lambda x: prefix_dict[x])` takes each value in the column and returns the relevant value from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT assign the value, like `database['Age'] = 65.0`. This will replace the value of 'Age' with 65.0 to every record. So, in the remainder of `i`, `math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True` will be always False because the column `Age` doesn't have `NaN` anymore.

I would suggest you to use `df.iterrows()` to iterate over dataframe and `df.at` to assign value to the specific cell of the record. The below code should work.

```
for i, row in database.iterrows():
    if math.isnan(database['Age'][i]) == True:
        if database['Prefix'][i] == ' Capt.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Col.':
            age = 65.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Sir.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Major.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Rev.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Lady.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Dr.':
            age  = 47.5
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Don.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Jonkheer.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mrs.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' the Countess.':
            age  = 36.5
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mr.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Ms.':
            age  = 29.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mme.' or database['Prefix'][i] == ' Mlle.':
            age  = 24.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Miss.':
            age  = 21.0
        elif database['Prefix'][i] == ' Master.':
            age  = 3.5

        database.at[i,'Age'] = age
```